# Cannot save Libre Office-Draw files

Tags: libreoffice

The error message is: *Error saving the document.*

I used synaptic to completely remove all installed LO packages. I deleted the hidden .cache files from/home/user. I re-installed LibreOffice. Problem is still there. Interestingly, I CAN save LO-Write files, but not LO-Draw files.

Suggestions what I can try next?

Comment: Suggestions: Have you tried safe mode i.e. `libreoffice --safe-mode`? Else need more info: Include the version i.e. run `libreoffice --version` in Terminal and see the output; Describe the file content i.e. ASCII/Unicode text, language font, drawing objects, etc (Edit your question to add these).

Answer (score 0):

try: TOOLS / OPTIONS - open cl enable

Hope this helps